# invalid embedded statement error 88

Tags: c#

Why does the following fail:

```
while (true)
   int a;

if(true)
   int a;

if(true)
   int a = 5;

if(true)
  int a = somestaticfunction();
```

apperently if fails with: "invalid embedded statement error 88"
on visual studio.

Comment: Which of the four statements fails?

Comment: Supposing it would work, what's the purpose?

Comment: All of them fail. The purpose would be using the somestaticfunction to change something, even though i don't use it's return value. It should be a compilation error.

Comment: @JohnSmith - It **is** a complication error?! *(using VS2010)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an [good explanation](http://web.archive.org/web/20111104035854/http://murrayon.net/2009/09/variable-declaration-restrictions.html) of what is going on, it is part of the language specification. It seems Objective C, Java and C also have the same restrictions. You can work around it by enclosing your statements like so.

```
while(true)
    {int a;}

if(true)
    {int a;}

if(true)      
    {int a = 5;}      

if(true)      
    {int a = somestaticfunction();}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cant be written like that in C#. You should change it like below else it will generate [Compiler Error CS1023:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaw06638%28vs.80%29.aspx) which says:

> An embedded statement, such as the statements following an if
>   statement, can contain neither declarations nor labeled statements.

```
        while (true)
        {
               int a;
        }
if(true)
{
   int a;
}

if(true)
{
   int a = 5;
}

if (true)
{
    int a = somestaticfunction();
}
```